# ServiceStack: is it open source? or does it require a license?

Tags: servicestack

I'm looking into ServiceStack, I see it referenced as open source some places but other places it looks like you need a license to use it.

Is it open source like things like Spring, Hibernate, JBoss, where you just need a license if you want some support and you can still use it for free as much as you need?  Or is it not open source at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact the vendor or project directly to ask about licensing questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's dual-licensed, the source code on GitHub is [licensed under AGPL/FOSS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/license.txt) whilst the official binary NuGet packages is licensed under [ServiceStack's commercial license](https://servicestack.net/terms) which can be used without a license up to built-in [free-quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas). A [commercial license](https://servicestack.net/pricing) is required for unrestricted usage.

Comment: So building your own binaries from source is allowed and unrestricted?

Comment: @TritonMan You can use the AGPL/FOSS License in projects that are OSS as well.

Comment: The current documentation at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text has a note and a link to https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.62.md#servicestacktext-is-now-free which states: "To celebrate our initial release supporting .NET Core, we're now making ServiceStack.Text completely free for commercial or non-commercial use." Yet none of the available licenses in various packages seem to reflect this fact.